# Keep a variable already created after a process is finished in python

Tags: python, wxpython

I've build a GUI with wxPython in which I use a process to build a table to feed some charts when I click a button.

I build the table and I store it in to a variable to use the information to feed my matplotlib chart.

My problem is that when my chart is finished, based on the already constructed table stored in a variable and the process is finished, I loose the information of that variable and I need to use that same information to make my plot interactive (i.e. to change the plot from line to bar, or stacked or whatever), but the only way I've found is to re run the process to build the table over and over again.

Is there a way to use the stored information of that variable in other processes / modules / charts? I mean, is there a way to keep "active" my variable no matter the process where it was created was finished?

Thanks a lot for your guidance :)

Comment: i think you are looking for a database

Comment: Yes, `store` it in a file

Answer (score 1):

This is done rather easily with the [pickle module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) Here is a simple working example

```
from pickle import dumps, loads
a_variable = 15 # arbitrary value

with open("a_file.txt", "wb") as fileobj:
    # create a pickle string representation of the data
    fileobj.write(dumps(a_variable))


# Then to load it from another process

with open("a_file.txt", "rb") as fileobj:
    # load the pickle string representation of the data
    a_variable = loads(fileobj.read())
```

Comment: Sweet! Works with multiple variables too. `fileobj.write(dumps([x,y,z]))` `a,b,c = loads(fileobj.read())`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I will try it right now :D